# Mock throwing a null pointer exception. New to mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock

I'm trying to test the following method

```
  MainClass {
    ....
        Client client;
        WebTarget target;
        boolean doLogin(MultivaluedMap<String, String> headers) {

             client = getRestClient();
             target = client.target(BASE_URL))
                    .path("v1/login");
              MultivaluedMap<String, Object> castedHeaders = castMap(headers);//casts headers by entry.
              Response loginRsp = target
                    .request().headers(castedHeaders)     
                    .post(Entity.entity(buildIusLoginEntity(),
                                        MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE));
              if (loginRsp.getStatus() != HttpServletResponse.SC_OK) {

                    return false;
              }
              return true;
        }
   }
```

Using the following test class

```
  @Test
  public void testdoLoginNegative() {
            MainClass m = spy(new MainClass());
            Client mockClient = mock(Client.class);
            WebTarget target = mock(WebTarget.class);

            Response loginRsp = Response.status(500).build();
            doReturn(mockClient).when(m).getRestClient();
            when(mockClient.target(anyString()).path(anyString())).thenReturn(target);
            //NPE on next line.
            when(target.request().headers(any(MultivaluedMap.class)).post(any(Entity.class))).thenReturn(loginRsp);// this line throws a Null pointer exception. 
            Assert.assertFalse(m.doIusLogin(getMockHeaders()));
   }
```

However, my mock seems to show a null pointer exception as indicated in the source code. Any thoughts on what I could be doing wrong.. would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Post your stack trace.

Comment: The stack trace just shows a Null Pointer exception on the line indicated in the test class. Nothing more.

Comment: If you break the code into separate lines instead of calling the next function on the result of the last function, the stack trace will indicate the line where the error exists, and you won't have to play this lame guessing game wbout what's failing - where the null is being returned.

Comment: @atk  How can I break the code down any further? There is only one action performed on 'target` in the line where the NPE is thrown, basically the post. Thats about it.

Comment: target.request().header() is two separate function calls (and several more within the argument to headers), but they are made on the same line. It could be r = target.request(); h = r.heqders(); (with newline in between, of course) If you want to simplify your code, try to do as few things per line as possible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You try to use **deep stubbing** without preparing your mock objects. Try

```
 WebTarget target = mock(WebTarget.class, Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
```

The difference is, that the mock without deep stubbing returns default values on method calls (usually null). If you enclose such a call with `Mockito.when` this does not have an effect, but if you append further calls this leads to `NullPointerException`s, e.g. in

```
target
  .request()                          // return null
  .headers(any(MultivaluedMap.class)) // NullPointerException
  .post(any(Entity.class)))
```

However I would expect

```
mockClient
  .target(anyString())                // should return null
  .path(anyString()))                 // should throw NullPointerException
```

to fail too with `NullPointerException`, without activating deep stubs with

```
Client mockClient = mock(Client.class, Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
```

Not that activating **deep stubbing** may be convenient for writing tests, but it can lead to strange behaviors in the tested code.